# How to get the new data update from a json url in android?

Tags: java, android, json

I am working in an online radio streaming project. I play the stream from a url and parsing the sound track info from another json url. All that I did is I repeatedly parse the json after every 10 seconds thats why when the sound track is changing I can get the track info of that specific track. But the json file is being updated 30+ sec before the track changes, thats why sometimes there is a noticeable dissimilarity between the track and the track info.

Here is my asyncTask class where I am playing the stream.

```
public class RadioPlayer extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(params[0]);
                mediaPlayer.prepare();

            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SecurityException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            // might take long! (for buffering, etc)
            mediaPlayer.start();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        }
```

and here is the handler where I am updating the track info after every 10 seconds:

```
private void getSongStatistics() {
        r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                try {
                    title = tsp.parseInitiator();
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {

                    Log.i("title", title);
                    try {
                        String[] subTitles = title.split("-");
                        tvTitle.setText(subTitles[1]);
                        tvArtist.setText(subTitles[0]);
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        tvArtist.setText(title);
                    }
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 10000);

                }

            }
        };

        handler.postDelayed(r, 10000);

    }
```

Is there any solution by which I may get rid of this weird problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [push](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) instead of polling to update data.

Comment: How can I do this, plz give me a referance :)

Comment: Um, the push text IS a link.

Comment: I am not familiar in GCM, I have to learn that first, if some other ways are there u can suggest as I need to finish this project fast :)

Comment: Aside from suggesting you poll at a faster frequency, no. Implementing GCM is straight forward and is, likely, the best solution.